# How to split value in string as same as array using javascript?

Tags: javascript

For this my code, when click on `GET DATA` i want to get `element[0]` ===> `1.png` , how to do ?

```js
function xx_fn() {
  var image_pack_val = document.getElementById("image_pack").value;
  var image = [image_pack_val][0]
  alert(image);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="xx_fn()">
  GET DATA
</div>
<br>
<input type="hidden" id="image_pack" value="'1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png','7.png','8.png','9.png','10.png'">
```

Comment: @mahan - no need to change all our clicks to a button. It does not change the script in any way

Comment: @Huangism Your comment itself isn't helpful. If you can't add anything in a positive manner, don't bother posting.

Comment: @SteveHansell the google link has info on how to split a string which is helpful info, a bit of research is required for someone how is asking a question and this one doesn't show any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using replace and split

you may want to use a button instead of clicking a `div`

```js
function xx_fn() {
  var image_pack_val = document.getElementById("image_pack").value;
  var image = image_pack_val.replace(/'/g,"").split(",")[0]
  console.log(image);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="xx_fn()">
  GET DATA
</div>
<br>
<input type="hidden" id="image_pack" value="'1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png','7.png','8.png','9.png','10.png'">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match the data and take the *n*th element of it.

```js
function xx_fn() {
  var image_pack_val = document.getElementById("image_pack").value,
      allImages = image_pack_val.match(/[^',]+/g);

    console.log(allImages);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="xx_fn()">GET DATA</button>
<br>
<input type="hidden" id="image_pack" value="'1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png','7.png','8.png','9.png','10.png'">
```

Comment: Not work when use `var image = image_pack_val.match(/[^']+/)[1]` for get element 2

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove single quotes `'` and then split on the comma `,`.

```js
function xx_fn() {
  let imageNameList = document.getElementById("image_pack").value;

  // remove all single quotes `'` and split on commas `,`
  let imageNames = imageNameList.replace(/'/g, "").split(",");
  console.log(imageNames[0]);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="xx_fn()">
  GET DATA
</div>
<br>
<input type="hidden" id="image_pack" value="'1.png','2.png','3.png','4.png','5.png','6.png','7.png','8.png','9.png','10.png'">
```

Comment: beat you by 20 seconds